# How to plot solutions to equations on a unit circle in complex plane

Tags: plotting

I have the following code to solve the equations, and wanted to plot them on unit circle on the complex plane, one by one. For example, this code gives me $6$ solutions, thus I would like to plot six circles, and on each, plot one of solutions **as a unit vector** on it.

```
sol = Solve[
  Sin[a - b] + Sin[a] == 0 && Sin[b - a] + Sin[b] == 0 && 
   Sin[-a] + Sin[-b] == 0, {a, b}]
```

[image]

Any idea? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is not clear to me,what exactly you want. a and b are only defined up to a multiple of Pi. Therefore it makes sense to plot them on the unit cycle.  That would give 2 points, one for a and one for b. However, what do you mean by "as a vector"?

Comment: @DanielHuber For example, the first solution gives $a=2\pi c_1,b=-2\pi c_2$, therefore I need to plot two vectors on the unit circle: $(\cos(2\pi c_1),\sin(2\pi c_1)$ and $(\cos(-2\pi c_2),\sin(-2\pi c_2))$

Comment: Since `c` is required to be an integer, both `{Cos[2 Pi c], Sin[2 Pi c]}` and `{Cos[-2 Pi c], Sin[-2 Pi c]}` are the point `{1, 0}`

Answer (score 1):

```
ContourPlot[{Sin[a - b] + Sin[a] == 0, Sin[b - a] + Sin[b] == 0, 
  Sin[-a] + Sin[-b] == 0}, {a, -10, 10}, {b, -10, 10}, 
 PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

From above plot,we can find that all of `{a,b}` is the intersection of three contours,it means that only two independent equations in the original three equations. We can verified this by

```
Simplify[Sin[-a] + Sin[-b] == 0, 
 Sin[a - b] + Sin[a] == 0 && Sin[b - a] + Sin[b] == 0]
```

> `True`

And we can plot all the points by `MeshFunction`.

```
ContourPlot[{Sin[a - b] + Sin[a] == 0} , {a, -10, 10}, {b, -10, 10}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {Function[{a, b}, Sin[a - b] + Sin[a]], 
   Function[{a, b}, Sin[b - a] + Sin[b]]}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], Red], ContourStyle -> Opacity[.1],
  PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

The same as

```
Graphics[{Red, Point[{a, b}]} /. 
  Table[Solve[
     Sin[a - b] + Sin[a] == 0 && Sin[b - a] + Sin[b] == 0 && 
      Sin[-a] + Sin[-b] == 0, {a, b}] /. {C[1] -> c1, 
     C[2] -> c2}, {c1, -2, 2}, {c2, -2, 2}], Axes -> True]
```

[image]

## OP

For `a` or `b`,`AngleVector[a]` or `AngleVector[b]` have only four points.

```
Graphics[{Red, Point[AngleVector[a]], Point[AngleVector[b]]} /. 
  Table[Solve[
     Sin[a - b] + Sin[a] == 0 && Sin[b - a] + Sin[b] == 0 && 
      Sin[-a] + Sin[-b] == 0, {a, b}] /. {C[1] -> c1, 
     C[2] -> c2}, {c1, -10, 10}, {c2, -10, 10}], Axes -> True]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Could you explain why 'we can find that all of {a,b} is the intersection of three contours,it means that only two independent equations in the original three equations.' ?